# Windows access device on different subnet

Tags: networking, subnet

I am running a device in my local network and want to access it from a different subnet. I can't change the IP address of the device.
I want to access it from a software in windows where I can enter the IP address. How do I configure my windows so that I can access the other subnet? Do I have to do any other configuration on my local network?
I am very new to this stuff so I hope that my question is clear.

Thanks for your help.
-Moritz

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to communicate to the that device may be change your computer IP to that subnet too. If you don't want to that, there may be some problem complex to solve like NAT traversal since the device may not supply that function and it may not connect to your computer first.

Comment: Thanks. I will first try to change the address of the device I am trying to access, if that doesn't work then I will try to change the one of my PC. I don't really know if I am allowed to change the IP address of my PC, so I am trying the other one first.